# How to get RPS metrics in JMeter and send them to InfluxDb?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, influxdb, jmeter-plugins

The problem is that I need to get RPS in JMeter and I don't know what exactly plugin to use. But the biggest problem is how to send this custom metrics to InfluxDb. Pls, describe the whole route to do it, thx!
JMeter - 5.4.1
InfluxDb - v2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [metrics which are exposed to the Backend listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html#metrics) don't include RPS, however if you [install Grafana and configure it to use your InfluxDB as the data source](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-grafana-to-monitor-jmeter-non-gui-results-part-2) you can calculate the "throughput" ([number of requests per second](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html))

[image]

The screenshot is from [this dashboard](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/5496)

Comment: Thx a lot for this solution!)